# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu not functioning

Tags: html

im starting bootstrap and i have been following some tutorials. I have recently came across the dropdown menu but i can't seem to get it going. I've searched for answers on whether i have referred bootstrap correctly but it looks like i have it correct.

Can someone help?

Thanks

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">"
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>    
  </head>
  
  <body>


    <div class= "header">
     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
     <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="drop down">
             Cool Button<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

       
    <div class = "container3">
     <div class = "row"> 
                <div class"row">
     <div class="well">
                     <a href=""class="btn">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-primary">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-success">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-info">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-warning">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-danger">button</a>                       
                        <hr>
                                              
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Gift Your Friends<br><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-gift" ></span></a>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </div>                                                
        </div>
        
        <div class ="container">
         <form action="">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="element 1">This is the text of the label</label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-1" class="form-control">
                </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="element 1">This is the text of the label 2</label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-1" class="form-control">
                </div>
             <p class="help-block">Enter your password with Capital letters and Numbers included</p>
            </form> 
            
            <hr>
            
         <form action="" class ="form-inline">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="element 3"></label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-3" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                </div> 
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="element 4"></label>
                    <input type="password" id="element-4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                <a href="" class ="btn btn-info">Sign In</a>
            </form>                       
        </div>    
    </div>     
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


  </body>
  
</html>
```

```
    <div class= "header">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="drop down">
                Cool Button<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="">1ool</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2ool</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3ool</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4ool</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>


    <div class = "container3">
        <div class = "row"> 
                <div class"row">
                    <div class="well">
                        <a href=""class="btn">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-primary">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-success">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-info">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-warning">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-danger">button</a>                       
                        <hr>

                        <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Gift Your Friends<br><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-gift" ></span></a>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </div>                                                
        </div>

        <div class ="container">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="element 1">This is the text of the label</label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-1" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="element 1">This is the text of the label 2</label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-1" class="form-control">
                </div>
             <p class="help-block">Enter your password with Capital letters and Numbers included</p>
            </form> 

            <hr>

            <form action="" class ="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="element 3"></label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-3" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="element 4"></label>
                    <input type="password" id="element-4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                <a href="" class ="btn btn-info">Sign In</a>
            </form>                       
        </div>    
    </div>     
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have not instantiated the toggle. To do so just add `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); }); </script>` in your body

Comment: See it working below in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `drop down`. It should rather be `data-toggle="dropdown"`

Also, You have to call the `dropdown()` on the element, once your DOM is loaded.

Add this to instantiate the dropdown. This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>    
  </head>
  
  <body>


    <div class= "header">
     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
     <div class="dropdown">
         <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
             Cool Button<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">4</a></li>            
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

       
    <div class = "container3">
     <div class = "row"> 
                <div class"row">
     <div class="well">
                     <a href=""class="btn">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-primary">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-success">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-info">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-warning">button</a>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-danger">button</a>                       
                        <hr>
                                              
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Gift Your Friends<br><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-gift" ></span></a>
                    </div>                   
                </div>
            </div>                                                
        </div>
        
        <div class ="container">
         <form action="">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="element 1">This is the text of the label</label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-1" class="form-control">
                </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="element 1">This is the text of the label 2</label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-1" class="form-control">
                </div>
             <p class="help-block">Enter your password with Capital letters and Numbers included</p>
            </form> 
            
            <hr>
            
         <form action="" class ="form-inline">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="element 3"></label>
                    <input type="text" id="element-3" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
                </div> 
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="element 4"></label>
                    <input type="password" id="element-4" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox"></div>
                <a href="" class ="btn btn-info">Sign In</a>
            </form>                       
        </div>    
    </div>     
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

/* Instantiate the dropdown once DOM loaded.*/
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); 
}); 
</script>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: I have mentioned the changes in the comments to question. I ll add the same in my answer as well. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Xufox: You are right. I have added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: Hey thanks, i can understand how it works now! But i am still having problems to getting the code to work, even though i have pasted your script into my document. Is it the Jquery link not working or what?